# Definition of restriction of relation

Tags: definition, relations

let be $\mathcal{R}$ a binary relation on $X$, and $\mathcal{T}$ a binary relation on $Y$, $\mathcal{T}$ is restriction of $\mathcal{R}$ if:

1) $Y \subseteq X$

2) $\forall a,b \in Y( a T b \leftrightarrow a R b)$

Is correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since a relation on $X$ is a subset of $X\times X$, if you have a subset $Y$ of $X$ then you can restrict your relation taking the intersection with $Y\times Y$.

Comment: @Sigur, ok thanks.. therefore $\forall a,b \in Y( a T b \wedge a R b)$?

Comment: $T$ should coincide with $R$ on $Y$.

Comment: okok..therefore $\mathcal{T}=\mathcal{R} \cap (Y \times Y)$?